# How to integrate the Facebook login in progressive web application

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-login, progressive-web-apps

I am building a Progressive web application with IONIC 3. I am following -

> https://medium.com/@fraxool/add-facebook-login-to-your-ionic-3-app-the-step-by-step-guide-88879e391a3b

Now the problem is when I am using `ionic serve` then in the browser when I am clicking on `Login with Facebook` button,

[image]

then it is showing me an error on the console as

> Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but Cordova is
>   not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a
>   device/simulator cordovaWarn @ vendor.js:60197 main.js:1058 Error
>   logging into Facebook cordova_not_available

I can understand that as I am using the browser, and Ionic serve will never generate Cordova files, so what is the right way to implement the Facebook login in an Ionic progressive web application.

Comment: After getting build. You can test in your real device.

Comment: I am making PWA which will run in browser.

Comment: The [@ionic-native/facebook](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) plugin says "Use the Facebook Connect plugin to obtain access to the native FB application on iOS and Android". If you want to use Facebook connect on the web you'll have to use a different plugin.